# Sagemaker training job producing different results then running job locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

This is a strange error. I have a `src.py` file that basically runs a training job for a computer vision model. I get these results running the `src.py` file locally:

```
                    precision    recall  f1-score   support

  normal (Class 0)       0.99      0.98      0.98       393
blockage (Class 1)       0.96      0.98      0.97       205

          accuracy                           0.98       598
         macro avg       0.97      0.98      0.97       598
      weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98       598
```

and these results running on sagemaker training job

```
                    precision    recall  f1-score   support
  normal (Class 0)       0.66      1.00      0.79       393
blockage (Class 1)       0.00      0.00      0.00       205

         accuracy                            0.61       598
         macro avg       0.33      0.50      0.40       598
      weighted avg       0.43      0.66      0.52       598
```

The only difference in running the file locally vs sagemaker is I get the following error or warning message on sagemaker:

```
 UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
```

If anyone ran into a similar issue or has any recommendations I would greatly appreciate it. Happy to add more code to this post if needed.

Comment: Do you mean you're running the script in local mode and on a remote instance? Do they both use the same datasets? The undefined metric seems to be because some of your observations don't have any predictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to certain tensorflow version sets as well as the opencv-python package. I resolved this issue defining the tensorflow estimator like this

```
keras_estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point=sm_script,
    role=workflow_execution_role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type=training_instance,
    dependencies=[sm_script, 'requirements.txt'],
    sagemaker_session=sm_sess,
    framework_version="2.11",
    base_job_name='{}-training'.format(base_name),
    py_version="py39",
    distribution={"parameter_server": {"enabled": True}},
    metric_definitions=[
        {'Name': 'validation_accuracy', 'Regex': "Belt Vision accuracy = ([0-9.]+)"},
        {'Name': 'validation_f1', 'Regex': "Belt Vision f1 = ([0-9.]+)"}]
)
```

This ensured that I am using python 3.9 (py_version="py39") and the tensorflow framework version (framework_version="2.11"). Here is the requirements.txt I used that fixed the issue:

```
sagemaker==2.173.0
scikit-learn==1.3.0
awswrangler==3.2.1
boto3==1.28.1
numpy==1.24.3
opencv-python==4.7.0.72
```